# Triple integral and mass

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

An object occupies the solid region bounded by the upper nappe of the cone $$z^2=9x^2+y^2$$ and the plane $$z=9$$ Find the total mass of the object if the mass density at $\space (x,y,z) \space$ is equal to the distance from $\space (x,y,z) \space$ to the top.

I switched to spherical coordinates, I can't find the right bounds... The answer is $$243/4 \pi,$$ I tried many ways, nothing is working so I would appreciate if someone showed me the correct way to do this.

Comment: Could you show us your work? Did you write the explicit expression for the density? How did you set up the integral?

Comment: Upper nape is the upper part of the double cone. I only changed the coordinates to spherical and tired to solve this so there's not much to show... I think I have an issue with understanding the equation for density. Is it going to be $$sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$? Which is equal to $$r$$? Also how am I supposed to compute bound for r?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is the distance of $(x,y,z)$ from the origin $(0,0,0)$. While in your question you say that the density is the distance from the top. By that you mean the distance from $z=9$ ? In that case the density is $9-z$.

Comment: Are you sure about the answer? I got the triple of that.

Comment: I get the same as @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Ok, so then density $$ (r^2sin^2(y) + (9-rcos(y))^{1/2} $$. (I don't know if it's going to look good).Bounds for r are 0 and 3? If we let $$ x=rcosxsiny, y=rsinxcosy, z=rcosy$$

Comment: Well, I copied the answer from book, maybe there was a mistake.

Comment: @Awerde The density is $\rho(x,y,z) = 9-z$ since it is the distance of $(x,y,z)$ from $z=9$, right?

Comment: Oh, okat that sounds about right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density is $\rho(x,y,z) = 9-z$, the mass is $M = \iiint_V \rho(x,y,z) dxdydz$, where $V$ is the region occupied by the solid in your question.

$$
M = \int_0^9 dz(9-z)\iint_{\Omega_z} dx dy
$$
where $\Omega_z = \{ (x,y): 0 \leq 9x^2+y^2\leq z^2\}$ and $|\Omega_z| =  \iint_{\Omega_z} dx dy= \frac{\pi}{3}z^2$

Hence $M = \int_0^9 (9-z) \frac{\pi}{3}z^2 dz  = \frac{729 \pi}{4}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Helped me a lot :)